# Issue in converting ActiveReports 6 to ActiveReports 7

Tags: report, activereports, componentone

in one of my projects I am currently using `ActiveReports` 6 and m planning to move to ComponentOne's ActiveReports 7. Basically I have downloaded trial version of ActiveReports 7 as of now... In the "Tool" menu, when I click on the "`Convert to ActiveReports 7`" I get a popup notifying... "`Member Not Found - Exception from HResult : 0x80020003 DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND`"

This is basically stopping me from my upgrading the reports. I tried to uninstall and re-install the `ActiveReports7` on my machine. Did it several times, but the same issue exists. I tried to google a lot but could not find any documentation related to this problem.

Can anybody please help me solve this?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio 2012? 
Which version of ActiveReports 7?

You can find the full version number of Visual Studio in the Help > About dialog. You can find the version of ActiveReports by looking at one of the assemblies.

Comment: Hi Scott, I am using Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 (Version 11.0.60315.01 Update 2) and ComponentOne ActiveReports Developer by GrapeCity, inc. and the version is (7.1.7470.0)... Can you guide me why this is happening? I am currently using the trial version of the ActiveReports 7. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is happening. I asked a PM on the AR team about this and he is trying to reproduce it. He suspects it is related to something specific in your project. Can you try it with a very simple/plain AR7 report on the same machine and see if that works?

Answer (score 2):

I've done a fair bit of this, both from 6 to 7 and from 3 to 7. Easiest way I've found to do it is to export the RPX file from the v6 report, and import it into v7. To do this go to the report designer in v6, and you should see a reports menu. Select the save option and it will let you save the RPX file somewhere. Then create a blank v7 report, and from the same menu select the load option, and load the file you've just created. If you have code alongside the report, simply paste it into the new report's class file. You might need to correct a couple of namespaces, but I don't recall there being much to do.

If you're going from v3 then you need to add an extra step, as they have changed the RPX format a bit. First you need to export from v3, then import into v6. Exporting from v6 translates the format to something v7 can understand, so import the result of that into v7 and you're good to go

Comment: RPX format has not changed, it has only gone through addition of more elements for new layout features.  You can load rpx from current version to previous versions and vice versa.  The API just ignores the ones that it is not aware of.
Report menu option in VS is one way to update the reports, but they are specific to RPX format only.  It will not help for code based report and its underlying event code and such.  It is still recommended that you use the Converter to update to later version of ActiveReports.

Comment: contd from prev post: I would request that you provide us with projects/reports that are causing issues and we will look into them immediately.

Comment: I've just tried several RPX files exported from a VB6 project, and they've all successfully imported into the latest version of ActiveReports 7 under VS2012. Not sure at this point if the problem I had in the past was related to specific reports, or if something has improved in AR7 SP1, but it certainly seems okay now

Answer (score 1):

Anand

Would you be able to try to convert a sample project(that is part of the installer) from ActiveReports 6 to 7?  That will help us determine if the particular project/report that you have is the issue or it is a problem in general.

Comment: Hi Rajnish, I tried to convert the sample project from AR6 to AR7 and it worked well. I don't know, why it did not work for me in my project. :(

Comment: Would you be able to send the project to us?  Please email me at rajnish.sinha@grapecity.com.

Comment: Hi Rajnish, basically it's a client project so I cannot share with anybody.... But Just FYI I asked one of my colleague to work on the conversion and he was able to do it successfully.... Through TFS I took the latest version and it worked well, but I am still trying to figure out why it did not work at my end....

I had un-installed and reinstalled AR 7 several times before taking the latest version, but it did not work. The problem is still a mystery for me.